# Clustered index on random order column

Tags: sql-server, index, clustered-index

I have an existing table named “Orders” in our system. OrderID is the primary key in this table – it is a clustered index. I have a new table designed  as shown below for “OrderCompanyDetails”. It has a `1-to-1`  relationship with Orders table. In the new table OrderID is kept as the clustered primary key.

Data gets inserted into the new table only when the Order is approved. So the OrderID getting inserted into the new table may not be in sequence. The OrderID 10 may get inserted before OrderID 5, depending on which order is approved first.

Having the clustered index on OrderID  helps my queries. But the clustered index is on a column which gets data in a random sequence. Is it a bad index design? If yes, should I add a new meaningless identity column with name OrderCompanyDetailID and make that as clustered index?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders]
(
    [OrderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderType] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [StatusCD] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOnDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__Orders__CreatedOn]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Orders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [OrderID] ASC
    )
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderCompanyDetails](
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [POCompanyCD] [char](4) NULL,
    [VendorNo] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [CreatedOnDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OrderCompanyDetails_CreatedOn]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderCompanyDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [OrderID] ASC
    )
)
```

**UPDATE**

Recently read article [Ever-increasing clustering key – the Clustered Index Debate……….again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/). There is a comment in that

> Remember – narrow, static, unique, ever increasing – and usually a surrogate key instead of a natural key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. I decided to add a surrogate key (as identity column) in my table due to the following reasons

1. My usage scenario is that the table has many inserts.
2. The surrogate key helps to keep the ever increasing order for clustered index.
3. Ever increasing order is important for avoiding fragmentation and page split as explained in [Ever-increasing clustering key – the Clustered Index Debate……….again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/)

If the insert is too heavy (concurrently), the `ever increasing order` can create `PAGELATCH_EX` waits problem. Read [PAGELATCH_EX waits and heavy inserts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/blogdoezequiel/2013/05/23/pagelatch_ex-waits-and-heavy-inserts/) which mentions about `hash partitioning with a computed column` and [Bit Reversion](http://dangerousdba.blogspot.co.at/2011/10/bit-reversion.html)

Note: `Insert Hot Spot` problem can appear if workload involves many hundreds of concurrent threads inserting into the table.

Also read about `Insert Hotspot` in [Knee-Jerk Wait Statistics : PAGELATCH - Paul Randal](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/10/sql-performance/knee-jerk-wait-statistics-pagelatch) which says the following:

> I’ve seen an insert hotspot like this crop up when someone’s tried to remove index fragmentation problems by changing a random GUID cluster key to an int or bigint identity cluster key, but fail to test the new table schema under production loads.

Latch wait can be analysed using DMV mentioned in [Advanced SQL Server performance tuning - Paul Randal](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/advanced-performance-troubleshooting-waits-latches-spinlocks/) which uses `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`. Also refer [Updated sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks script](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/updated-sys-dm_os_waiting_tasks-script/)

[PAGELATCH_EX - sqlskills](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/pagelatch_ex/) identifies `Insert Hot Spot` and `Page Split` as two of the three possible reasons for PAGELATCH_EX.

Comment: [Page Split Mini-Series - Part II - Page Latch Contention](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/pearlknows/2013/07/26/page-split-mini-series-part-ii-page-latch-contention/) says `High wait times for latch-wait statistics is one possible indication of too many page splits. The latches are held in EX (exclusive) mode, therefore will show up in the waiting queue as PageLatch_EX.`

Answer (score 5):

The recommendation for clustered indexes is that they are ever-increasing or ever-decreasing, but that doesn't mean they have to be. GUIDs aren't increasing or decreasing unless you are using sequential GUIDs. Most people don't use sequential GUIDs.

If you are worried about the performance hit from page splits, then lower your fill factor to accommodate more inserts before a page split is needed. This is what is advised for GUIDs too if the GUID is the clustered index (I'm not saying it should be the clustered index, I'm saying **if** it is). Be careful how low you lower it though as it will impact read performance, which probably is important to you since you mentioned the clustered index on OrderID helps your queries.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is **Not necessarily**.

The purpose of the index is to assist in querying the table after insert, and you say that this index does that. The cost of this improvement are

1. That the index has additional overhead costs at insert- that is, that the new record has to be sorted among the existing records in terms of the clustered index values.
2. Maintenance of the index and related statistics to ensure that the improvement continues after the initial implementation. This could include rebuilding statistics and/or indexes periodically.

If the cost of the maintenance and/or insert overhead is greater than the benefit provided by the performance gain on selects using the table in the context it is operating, then the index should be rethought.

Comment: there's an additional drawback for this improvement I think: it will turn the previous index into a secondary index which causes all of the subsequences queries on that index becomes a two-lookups query, i.e. first finding the primary key in the secondary index and then find the data node in the clustered index using the primary key.